# Event mouse down javascript toElement

Tags: javascript, events, nicedit

When i'm handle click to edit area. i use folowing function

```
  Function.prototype.closureListener = function() {
        var __method = this, args = bkLib.toArray(arguments), object = rgs.shift(); 
        return function(e) { 
        e = e || window.event;
        if(e.target) { var target = e.target; } else { var target =  e.srcElement };
            return __method.apply(object, [e,target].concat(args) ); 
        };
    }
```

and add event

```
this.elm.addEvent('mousedown',this.selected.closureListener(this))
```

But when i click **at the end** of the line

```
asdasdasd<b>sdasdasdasd<b>
```

**sometimes** it's select like a target all body(as Element) or only sdasdasdasd.
What should i add that he took only sdasdasdasd but not all body.

P.S When i click somewhere in the middle it's always takes sdasdasdasd

P.S.S [nicEdit](http://kenai.com/nonav/projects/myadds/sources/source-code-repository/content/js/nicEdit.js?rev=23) i'm using this nicEdit panel.

Comment: What does `this` reference? What is `elm`? What is `selected`?

Comment: [nicEdit](http://kenai.com/nonav/projects/myadds/sources/source-code-repository/content/js/nicEdit.js?rev=23) i'm using this nicEdit panel.

Comment: Clicking _outside_ of the text chunk may well result in clicking outside of its parent element, so the result is not surprising... Try using `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`.

Comment: if i use e.currentTarget it's return me all #document.